# why can't write the number to it?

Tags: jquery

```
<ul class="newsct">
  <li><span class="listnum"></span><a href="#">test</a></li>
<li><span class="listnum"></span><a href="#">test</a></li>
<li><span class="listnum"></span><a href="#">test</a></li>
<li><span class="listnum"></span><a href="#">test</a></li>
<li><span class="listnum"></span><a href="#">test</a></li>
<li><span class="listnum"></span><a href="#">test</a></li>
<li><span class="listnum"></span><a href="#">test</a></li>

</ul>
```

i want to write 3,4,5,6,7 to  like this `<span class="listnum">3</span>`

i using the following code,but it doesn't work.

```
var len = $('.newsct li').length;
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
 if(i>=3){
        $('.newsct li .listnum').text()==i;
}
    }
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is wrong as a) You are setting the text to all elements matching `$('.newsct li .listnum')` in all iterations instead of just the current one and b) Your usage of `.text()` is incorrect.

This should work:

```
var len = $('.newsct li .listnum').each(function(i) {
    $(this).text(i+1); // add conditions as needed (note first item index is 0)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.newsct li .listnum').each(function(i,elem) {
    if (i>=3) $(elem).text(i);
});
```

or

```
for(var i=0, len = $('.newsct li').length; i<len ;i++){
     if(i>=3) $('.newsct li .listnum').eq(i).text(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to set the text:

```
var indexStart = 3;
$('.newsct li .listnum:gt('+indexStart +')').each(function(i) {
    $(this).text(indexStart + i);
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PyxP5/

if you just use text() you will get the text.

Comment: `$('.newsct li .listnum').text(i);` will set `i` as the text for **all** items matching `'.newsct li .listnum'`

Comment: yeah, though the code was filtering out the span elements, changed the code.

Answer (score 0):

$('.newsct li .listnum') will select all elements and we need to specify particular element so use get() and need to set text using text method

var len = $('.newsct li').length;
        for(var i=0;i=3){
            $('.newsct li .listnum').get(i).text(i);
    }
        }

Answer (score 0):

Use bellow code .should work

```
for(var i=0, len = $('.newsct li').length; i<len ;i++){      if(i>=3) $('.newsct li .listnum').eq(i).text(i); }
```